# DataMapper first_or_create always set certain field?

Tags: ruby, orm, sinatra, ruby-datamapper

I'm using the following with datamapper to create/get a new user from my db:

```
user = User.first_or_create({:id => data['id']})
```

This gets the user with id = data['id'] or creates it if it doesn't already exist.

I want to know how to set other attributes/fields of the returned object regardless of whether it is a new record or existing?

Is the only way to do this to then call `user.update({:field => value ...})` or is there a better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you could write it as one line:

```
(User.first_or_create(:id => data['id'])).update(:field => value)
```

with hashes for the parameters if you wish (or if you need to specify more than one); however, it's worth noting that this will only work if the model as specified by the `first_or_create` is valid. If `:name` were a required field, for instance, then this wouldn't work:

```
(User.first_or_create({:id => data['id'], :name => "Morse"})).update(:name => "Lewis")
```

as the creation in the first part would fail.

You could get around this by specifying the parameters needed for a new record with something like

```
(User.first_or_create({:id => data['id'], :name => "Morse"}, {:name => "Lewis"})).update(:name => "Lewis")
```

but this is unusually painful, and is difficult to read.

Also note that using `first_or_create` with an `:id` will attempt to create a model with that specific `:id`, if such a record doesn't exist. This might not be what you want.

Alternatively, you can use `first_or_new`. You can't call `update` on an object created using this, however, as the record won't exist (although I believe this might have worked in previous versions of DataMapper).

Comment: Thanks, that's great. In the end I used the first_or_create method to generate the User instance then called attributes= followed by save to set the attributes. I think this method uses the fewest SQL queries?

Answer (score 0):

Just for anyone coming across this answer, User.first_or_create({:id => data['id']}) does NOT "get the user with id = data['id'] or creates it if it doesn't already exist." It actually gets the first record in the table and changes its id t0 data['id'].

To actually get the first record with that id, or create it if it doesn't exist, you need to use a where clause:

```
User.where(id: data['id]).first_or_create
```